# flutter phone can't reach Internet though the app is correct

Tags: flutter, dart

I have cloned a repository which was shown in a youtube video in which the host got data from Internet. This is the repository https://github.com/md-weber/network_request_tutorial.
In the files the android files have the permission to go to the internet and my phone does have a internet connection. Any thoughts what could be wrong? I dont use an emulator if it is from importance

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right this is what you should do:

1. You open your `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the debug folder under `app/src`
2. There is a line `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` copy it
3. go to `AndroidManifest.xml` of the ***main*** folder and paste it there

You have only given permission to use the internet in debug mode, so it won't work in release mode.